# Doctrine inserting null for @ID field

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I have a user object I am trying to insert via Doctrine.

The key fields are

```
  /**
 * @ORM\Column(type="integer", name="id")
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
private $userId;
/**
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", name="login_name")
 */
private $loginName;
/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", name="display_name") 
 */
private $name;
```

In my controller code I can echo out the value of the $loginName field via the getLoginName() method on the object.

```
/**
 * @param mixed $loginName
 */
public function setLoginName($loginName)
{
    $this->loginName = $loginName;
}

/**
 * @return mixed
 */
public function getLoginName()
{
    return $this->loginName;
}
```

You can see the Controller code to do the insert here.

```
 if ($request->getMethod() == 'POST') {
        $form->bind($request);
        $login = $form->getData();

        $factory = $this->get('security.encoder_factory');
        echo($login->getLoginName());
        $encoder = $factory->getEncoder($login);
        $login->setPassword($encoder->encodePassword($login->getPassword(), $login->getSalt()));
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $em->persist($login);
        $em->flush();

        $this->get('session')->setFlash(
            'success',
            'Account Successfully Created'
        );
```

However, when I call persist and flush on my entity, the login_name field is getting '' put into it (empty space). I can't understand why the value is getting nulled out (I changed a DB setting to error when it comes in as non-unique).

There are associations against this class, but this is the primary so I am creating it first.

Any thoughtS?

Comment: Why did you not annotate $userId as the @Id?

Comment: Becuase that's the auto generated ID from the Mysql Table. And to use the built in auth framework in symfony it seemed like I had to use the login credentials as the ID.  But that isn't really relevant to why it has a ID field that has a value and it's inserting null

Comment: Thats not true. Have a look at the FOSUSerbundle, the users have an ID field as well, and that one is the @ID.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't get what you're doing here. You want `table.id` to be an auto-generated ID but you want `table.login_name` to be the primary key? Because that's how you have it setup

- [@Id is for primary keys](https://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/annotations-reference.html#annref-id)
- [@GeneratedValue defines how priamry keys are created](https://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/annotations-reference.html#annref-generatedvalue)

What I personally think you should want is for `table.id` to be the primary key, and for `table.login_name` to be unique

```
/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="integer", name="id")
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
private $userId;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", name="login_name", length=255, unique=true)
 */
private $loginName;
```

Answer (score 0):

So in testing I identified that you can't apply a generatedValue attribute to an Non-ID field. Once I removed that from the userID field (and allowed Mysql to handle that on it's own) things started to work again.